# TF question about robot arm

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I have Groovy, a pincher arm, and turtlebot.
I got success in "rosrun tf tf_echo base_link gripper_link", which shown TF data. But these data never change in accordance with time, though I changed the pose of gripper sometimes. Is it problematic? In my guess TF data should change and tell me the real-time pose of gripper. I don't know whether it's problem in URDF model issue(maybe URDF fails to connect with arm?).
Thanks so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157651/tf-question-about-robot-arm/) by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2014-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it. In launch file the joint publisher sentence should be commented out, because it's only used for fake robot.

---

Originally posted by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) with karma: 74 on 2014-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on 2014-05-09**:
Yantian
I too have ROS Groovy Turtlebot(create) & Dynamax Pincher Arm. I'm curious what packages u installed to control the arm? I did install the groovy dynamax packages but I understand older (pre Groovy) simple arm packages are depreciated and being updated to Moveit!

**Comment by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on 2014-05-09**:
I'm actually using phantomx pincher arm, and I'm not sure now that it's the same with U(but maybe). I'm now just using arbotix grooy 4.0 package(the driver) to control the arm, because other package including simple_arms and turtlebot_arms were gone, as what U said. But I'm also truing to fix then.

**Comment by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on 2014-05-09**:
Also, the arm.launch in turtlebot_arm_bringup package can be used to start the arbotix driver.